# Is there a LMS payload limit for messages sent?

Tags: lightning-message-service

I am looking to understand if there a payload size limit for LMS.

```
({
    handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var payload = {
            recordId: "some string",
            recordData: {
                value: "some value"
            }
        };
        cmp.find("sampleMessageChannel").publish(payload);
    }
})
```

I've looked at the documentation and looked around a bit and am unable to find a concrete number.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_publish.htm

If this isn't already documented, will run a test and post results for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LMS is strictly a client-side function, it doesn't involve the server at all, so there's no hard limit on resources, either payload size or number of calls per page. You can use it as much as you need to. You may run into problems if your browser runs low on memory, but that's device-dependent.